# MS Access 2012 Unresponsive to clicks when it has focus on citrix

Tags: ms-access, citrix

Recently, we have had various MS Access 2012 apps become unresponsive to mouse clicks.

This happens in both in either run or design modes for forms, reports, queries, etc.

Usually, when I put the focus on another program by bringing it up and clicking in it, then go back to the Access app - it is then responsive.

Now it is happening to our Citrix users and the trick doesn't always work.

Anyone have any ideas, fixes, solutions?

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken? Are all MS Access databases suffering from the same problem? Are you running a timer?

Comment: How many "Access 2012" apps are you running?  If that's not a typo then the easy answer to your question is: don't use [Alpha software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Alpha) in a production environment.

Comment: We only have about 6 access db's still in users hands.  They all connect to SQL Server 2005 as the back end via ODBC.  I believe the user in question had only one access app open.  When it happens to me, the app is not waiting on something.  You click on it and it's like clicking on the desktop.  Switch to something else and bingo, it's awake.  And yes, it is all access apps pretty much at random times.

Comment: Hmm, are things a lot slower than they used to be?

Comment: No timers either, good thought though.  And thanks for the help!

Comment: Slower? Yes I suppose so, however that is the purview of our IT dept.  They might have moved the user space somewhere, but hopefully that is not the issue since I have no influence there.

Comment: Well initially I would compile the database, then I would check the indexing on the tables, then I would compact and repair, then I would convert as many queries as I could to pass through queries. If things are still as slow then there may be another underlying problem, not to do with Access.